# I want to Dark mode like Telegram

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to Dark mode like Telegram.
I have used [animated_theme_switcher](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_theme_switcher) but not working like telegram dark mode.

This is telegram dark mode [video](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/BYXlWrDy6AQ). Switch dark mode animation outside and switch light mode animation inside.

This is my screen recorder [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1omDOqWNLwpxkTplzjK2udrZxLU99QTWe/view?usp=sharing). Switch dark mode animation outside and switch light mode also animation outside.

When I switching dark mode animation outside and switch light mode also animation outside. But I want switch dark mode animation outside and switch light mode animation inside.
Please help me!
Thank you.

And my code with [animated_theme_switcher](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_theme_switcher)

```
 Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: ThemeSwitcher.withTheme(
                builder: (_, switcher, theme) {
                  return IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      isDark = theme.brightness == Brightness.light;
                      switcher.changeTheme(
                        theme: theme.brightness == Brightness.light
                            ? darkTheme
                            : lightTheme, 
                      );
                    },
                    icon: Icon(
                        isDark
                            ? Icons.light_mode_rounded
                            : Icons.dark_mode_rounded,
                        size: 25),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```